# Knowing fatality rate for age groups and fatality rate for critical cases, how do we calculate rate of critical cases for an age group?

Tags: probability

I've taken statistics courses, but I wasn't the most attentive student, so this is probably a simple question.

I wanted to calculate the chance that at least one of a group would either die or be a critical case in the hospital if someone chose to work in a nursing home when infected with coronavirus.

I know the principle of 1 minus chance of it not happening and multiply for multiple events. So I was able to figure out the chance of at least 1 in a group dying if someone exposes the whole group to coronavirus.

1-((1-fatalityRate)*(1-fatalityRate) .... *(1-fatalityRate_n))

But I couldn't figure out how to get their chance of being a critical case by their age group, I know it should be possible to get a reasonable number since we have fatality rates by age from the chinese CDC, and we know that all deaths were included as critical cases and that of those critical cases 49% died so that means that there were 51% that were critical but did not die. So what's the equation to work backwards to get the chance of being critical but not dying? This is probably ridiculously easy and I'm just not seeing it.